# REST API Statistics of HERE Maps

Tags: here-api

I'm implementing the Nokia HERE REST API into my application and just wondered why the statistics are always empty.

I'm currently using the "Consumer Free" plan and I think my app downloads 250 - 750 tiles per day during development - but they aren't showing up there (In the statistics).

Is this simply to less data to show in the statistics?

https://developer.here.com/applications/{app_id}/usage

[image: Screenshot of Usage]

Comment: The transactions are recorded for the production environment,  kindly make sure the requests are being made to Production and not CIT environment. CIT urls have the domain *.cit.api.here.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our earlier reply
"The transactions are recorded for the production environment, kindly make sure the requests are being made to Production and not CIT environment. CIT urls have the domain *.cit.api.here.com"